# Our Customer Communities Plus Users can't customize Joined Reports

Tags: customer-community, joined-reports, report-builder, user-profile

We have a Community setup with Folders designed for each Client. In them, there are a series of folders with reports designed for their needs. [image] As you can see above, I noticed that one Client was unable to customize a report that I made for them, as there is no 'Customize' Button.

After some major research into why they weren't able to customize ANY of their reports, I came to the conclusion that they were able to customize all of their Reports, except for anything that was Joined.

I was curious if anyone else had this problem, or knew of why this would be the case?